# Intersection between two surfaces.

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, curves

Simple enough really. But this exact exercise is giving me trouble, you will see shorty.

Suppose $\Gamma$ is the curve, that comes from an intersection between:
$$ z^2=x^2-y^2 \tag1 \label1$$ and $$ x^2+y^2+2z^2=3 \tag2 \label2.$$

Calculate $\vec{T},\vec{N},$and$\vec{B}$, as well as the torsion and flexion curvature in the point $(1,0,-1)$

The actual exercise is quite straightforward. All I need is $\vec{r}(t)$ then plug the derivatives intoeuqations for those vectors as well as the torsion and flexion.

And so I went forth:
$x=r\cos(t)$,$y=r\sin(t)$, $x^2+y^2=r^2$;

From $\ref2$ I get $\tag3 \label3 r^2+2z^2=3 \\ 2z^2=3-r^2 $ from $\ref1$ $\tag4 \label4 z^2=r^2(\cos^2(t)-sin^2(t))$

Now if I combine what I know from $\ref3$ and $\ref4$ I get my r(t) (note, not the vector) giving me:
$$\tag5 \label5 r(t)=\left(\frac{3}{1+2\cos^2(t)-2\sin^2(t)}\right)^{1/2}$$
and with $\ref5$ finally (note: for simplicity will write $r(t)$ as $r$):
$$\tag6 \label6 \vec{r}(t)=(r\cos(t),r\sin(t),r(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))^{1/2})$$

All seems fine but when I try to check for the point $(1,0,-1)$ I simply can't my fit my $\vec{r}(t)$ to it. So I expect I did something wrong here. At closest I get $\vec{r}(0)=(1,0,1)$

Comment: How do you want to get a negative $z$ using a (positive) square root ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is exactly my problem. I probably messed up there. 

The point in question is given by my prof. I need to calculate all of the above in that point.

I really messed something in this parametrisation up and I can't find a different approach.

Comment: The first surface is a cone symmetric about the $x$-axis, so the two intersections with the ellipsoid will have constant $x$. The intersections are ellipses, so you should end up with something like $x=c$, $y=a\cos t$, $z=b\sin t$.

Comment: @amd Thanks. I'll try that right away.

Comment: See my update to the comment—it’s actually symmetric about the $x$-axis.

Comment: @KatptonLiamfuppinshire: hem, how do you solve $z^2=a$ ?

Comment: @amd Alright that, solved it. $c=1, b=-1, a=\sqrt{2}$ Thanks! Can you just copy your comment to the answer So i can flag this question as answered. Not sure if my score is high enough to answer my own question yet.

Comment: Actually, I was a bit hasty and steered you wrong. The intersection looked like it was planar but really isn’t, so $x$ isn’t going to be constant and the curves aren’t simple ellipses. However, the symmetry of the cone about the $x$-axis will still be useful: set $y=x\cos t$ and $z=x\sin t$ and see where that takes you. Use the fact that $(1,0,-1)$ lies on the intersection of interest to choose between the two possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the first equation as $x^2=y^2+z^2$. This surface is a cone with the $x$-axis as its axis of symmetry. Its cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are circles, which suggests trying the parameterization $y=x\sin t$, $z=x\cos t$. Plugging this into the equation of the ellipsoid gives $$x^2(\sin^2 t+2\cos^2 t+1)=3,$$ from which $$x^2 = {6\over5+\cos2t}.$$ There are actually two intersection curves, but we want the one on which the point $(1,0,-1)$ lies, so take the positive square root, yielding the parameterization $$\mathbf r(t) = \sqrt{6\over5+\cos2t}(1,\sin t,\cos t).$$ I’ll leave it to you to check that this in fact satisfies both equations. Solving $\mathbf r(t)=(1,0,-1)$ for $t$ produces $t=\pi$ and the rest, as you say, is a matter of plugging the function into formulas.